# How to get LatLng by clicking on rotating sphere (three.js)?

Tags: javascript, three.js

1) create earth object

```
self.earth = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.SphereGeometry(50, 32, 32), new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map: tex}));

THREE.ImageUtils.crossOrigin = '';
self.obj = new THREE.Object3D();
self.obj.add(self.earth);
// self.obj.rotation.y = 34.3;
```

2) intersects

```
var mouse3D = new THREE.Vector3(  );    

var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster(); 
mouse3D.set( ( (event.clientX) / window.innerWidth ) * 2 - 1, -( (event.clientY) / window.innerHeight ) * 2 + 1, 0.5 ).unproject(self.camera);raycaster.set(self.camera.position, mouse3D.sub(self.camera.position ).normalize());

var intersects = raycaster.intersectObject( self.earth );

if (intersects.length > 0) {

   object = intersects[0];

   r = 50; // radius   
   x = object.point.x ;
   y = object.point.y ;
   z = object.point.z ;
```

3) coords

```
var lat =  ( 90 - (Math.acos(y / r)) * 180 / Math.PI ) - 10;

var lon =  ((270 + (Math.atan2(x , z)) * 180 / Math.PI) % 360) - 10;
```

Its work, but rotating (self.obj.rotation.y = 34.3;) broke calculating, why?

Comment: Don't see how this could be the problem, but I think self.obj.rotation.y should be in radians not degrees (0.6021386). Maybe the issue is caused because you are rotating it 1,965.245 degreees?

Comment: Also, I'm assuming all of these pieces of codes live inside functions that get called via request animation frame or the like, because otherwise you are just rotating it once.

Comment: Finally, please give a better explanation of how the globe is "broken"

Comment: @PabloBarríaUrenda when adding any rotation (once or in loop function), i get incorrect latlng coords

Comment: Ok. I am completely speculating here, but maybe you need your lat and lon formulas to correct for the rotation of the sphere?